# Bootstrap: let text flow around text input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a "fill-the-gap" interface with bootstrap, where the users have to type in a missing word to complete a sentence.

How can I position the text input inline and let the remaining sentence flow around it?

This is my code so far:

```
elit at imperdiet dui accumsan <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" placeholder="...">
  </div>
</form> sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat
```

This is how it looks (text input surrounded by newlines):

[image]

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f58hzou3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution for you. Put all the text inside the `.form-group` class. I have to put additional `.d-inline` class for both `.form-inline` & `.form-group` class to display the text inline. Hope it will work for you.

Don't forget to follow my example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/BEXRqN)

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form class="form-inline d-inline">
    <p class="form-group d-inline ">
      1. elit at imperdiet dui accumsan
      <input type="text" class="form-control mx-2" id="textInput" placeholder="Fill the gap"> sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat.
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the text inside the form

```
<form class="form-inline">
elit at imperdiet dui accumsan 
  <div class="form-group mx-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" placeholder="...">
  </div>
sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9fmtwL7n/

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I misunderstood you. My native language is not English. But, I realized that you want to make the arrangement in one line?

```css
.ok {
    display: flex;
}
.ok div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ok">
<div>elit at imperdiet dui accumsan</div> <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" placeholder="...">
  </div>
</form><div>sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat</div>
</div>
```